# check multiple directory size which are in sequence using du

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, du

How can I get size of directory which are in sequence like *d1 d2 d3 d4* till *d100* i want to check the size of d50 to d100 using **du -sh** command

Answer (score 0):

```
du -sh d{50..100}
```

`{50..100}` will be expanded as 50 51...100

Test:

```
$du -sh asd{41..43}
4.0K    asd41
4.0K    asd42
4.0K    asd43
```